# How can I specify a resolution for fullscreen applications through cygwin/x?

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, xorg, resolution

Most easily explained with an example.

On my windows machine in cygwin I start the x server with:

```
matthew@cygwin $ startxwin
```

Then I ssh to my linux mint machine with X forwarding

```
matthew@cygwin $ ssh -Y mint-server
```

Then I want to start cinnamon

```
matthew@mint-server $ cinnamon
```

It then takes a really long time to start up because it's trying to forward my screen at 1080p. I'm hoping I can improve performance a lot by forcing the resolution lower (640x480) since I just need to some very basic things in the gui and 640x480 would be enough for me.

So, where can I set the resolution of fullscreen applications through the x server?

Comment: I've always had good performance using individual applications instead of a whole desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running the X server in Windowed mode limited to the size you want:

```
startx -- -screen 0 640x480
```

From the man page for startx, options for the X server are introduced by `--`, and from the [man page for xwin](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/XWin.1.html), it has the -screen option for setting the size of the X screen.

But I am somewhat doubtful that this will make anything any faster.